# Loop to create a chart for each row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a loop that will create a chart for each row in my Excel sheet. I can't use a sparkline.

```
Sub chartcreation()
'
 chartcreation Macro
'  
 Sub Main()

  x$ = 2

Do While Cells(x$, 2) <> ""

    Range("A1:Tx$").Select
    Range("Tx$").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("MAY!$A$1:$T$1",MAY!A$(x$)$T$x$")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").IncrementLeft 380.6249606299
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").IncrementTop -270

    x = x + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA can't legally nest procedures... `Sub...End Sub` can't be nested like this, does your code compile? What's your question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten your code below with what I believe you are looking for.  This will go through every row with a value in column B, create chart, and place the upper left corner of the chart in column U for that row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim strChrt As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastRow
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(x, "A"), ws.Cells(x, "T")).Select
        ws.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select

        strChrt = Trim(Replace(ActiveChart.Name, ActiveSheet.Name, ""))
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Left = ws.Cells(x, "U").Left
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Top = ws.Cells(x, "U").Top

    Next x

End Sub
```